# Replacing src on image with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace the src of an image and I currently have this:

```
if(('product-img img').src = "/webimages/blank.gif") {
   $(".product-img img").attr("src","/images/blank.gif");
}
```

It is working but it's happening to all the images on the page. I only want it to happen if the image src = /webimages/blank.gif. I've also tried `$(this).attr("src","/images/blank.gif");` anyone know what I'm missing? Thanks

Comment: have doubt... if(('product-img img').src = "/webimages/blank.gif") , here '$' missing also 'product-img' is what class the '.' (dot) missing.

Comment: Condition should be: `if($('.product-img img').attr('src') == "/webimages/blank.gif") {`

Comment: For starters, you need to use == not =. http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0022.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.product-img img[src="/webimages/blank.gif"]').attr("src","/images/blank.gif");
```

Comment: @AlexMurray, good to know ... if it helped please select as best answer :)

Comment: will do! you answered too fast still need to wait 2mins :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missging `=`, change `=` to `==`, the code should as follow:

```
if($('.product-img img').src == "/webimages/blank.gif") {
   $(".product-img img").attr("src","/images/blank.gif");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
if(('img.product-img').src == "/webimages/blank.gif") {
   $("img.product-img").attr("src","/images/blank.gif");
}
```